# Scroll function to navigate to appropriate section using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scrollto

My goal is to complete a dynamic single landing page using JavaScript. HTML and CSS files were already provided and I managed to build an unordered list by manipulating the DOM.

The thing that got me stuck is: When clicking an item from the navigation menu, the link should scroll to the appropriate section.
I cannot get this to work :/

Below is the JS code so far.

```
/* Declare variables for the fictive document and menu list to retrieve and store variables as unordered list */
const container = document.createDocumentFragment();
const menuList = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

/* Function to create the navigation menu as a clickable link */
function navigationLink(id, name) {
    const navLink = `<a class = "menu__link" data-id=${id}">${name}</a>`;
    return navLink;
}

/* Function for the navigation list, built as an unordered list */
function createNavigation() {
    for (let i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++) {
        const newMenuListItem = document.createElement('li');
        const menuListName = menuList[i].getAttribute('data-nav')
        const menuListID = menuList[i].getAttribute('id')
        newMenuListItem.innerHTML = navigationLink(menuListID, menuListName)
        container.appendChild(newMenuListItem);
    }
    /* Retrieve the id from the ul section to be added to the document fragment: container */
    const navBarMenu = document.getElementById('navbar__list')
    navBarMenu.appendChild(container);
}

// Add class 'active' to section when near the top of viewport
function setActiveClass() {
    for (let i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++) {
        if (isInViewport(menuList[i])) {
            menuList[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
        } else {
            menuList[i].classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
    }
}
```

To solve the problem I looked into another piece of code that I haven't been able to function properly.

```
function scrollToElement(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'A') {
        const menuListID = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        const menu = document.getElementById(menuListID);
        menu.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    setActiveClass();
});

const navBarMenu = document.getElementById('navbar__list')
navBarMenu.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    scrollToElement(event)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anchor to do this. This will make your life easier than trying to do this in js.

To use it, you just have to set an `id` to a node. Like `<div id="myFirstId"></div>` and then, set the `href` of your link to `#myFirstId`.

If you want your scroll to not be instant, you can add the `scroll-behavior: smooth` to the scrollable element.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#scrollable {
  overflow:auto;
}
#firstDiv {
  background-color: green;
  height: 700px
}
#secondDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
#thirdDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#firstDiv">firstDiv</a>
<a href="#secondDiv">SecondDiv</a>
<a href="#thirdDiv">thirdDiv</a>
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="firstDiv"></div>
  <div id="secondDiv"></div>
  <div id="thirdDiv"></div>
</div>
```

For your code, just change this line `<a class = "menu__link" data-id=${id}">${name}</a>`

To this `<a class="menu__link" href="#${id}">${name}</a>`

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, that looks creative. But can't I use the navLink I created:

Comment: @JonasAchouriSihlén Yes you can, just replace the `data-id` attr by `href` and add an "#" before the var. I'm gonna update the answer to show you how to do it